# Parsing response of web service which returns object not arrayofobjects

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am making an android application witch gets informations from a Web Service. I need a solution for parsing this result:

```
<Client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://lmggroup.net/">
<ID>12805</ID>
<PersonalNumber>0</PersonalNumber>
<EntryDate>2013-01-28T14:39:01</EntryDate>
<FirstName>0</FirstName>
<LastName>0</LastName>
<Address>0</Address>
<Phone>0601231569</Phone>
<Email>aaa@aaa.com</Email>
<OrganizationalUnitID>02901</OrganizationalUnitID>
<Password>aaaaaa</Password>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
</Client>
```

I've try this to solve this problem using the following code

```
public static ArrayList<UserContent> getUserContentList(String response)
{
    ArrayList<UserContent> result = new ArrayList<UserContent>();
    if (response != null && response.equals("") == false)
    {
        KXmlParser xmlParser = new KXmlParser();
        Document xmlDoc = new Document();

        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( bin );

        try
        {
            xmlParser.setInput(isr);
            xmlDoc.parse(xmlParser);
            Element xmlRoot = xmlDoc.getRootElement();
            if(xmlRoot != null)
            {
                Element[] xmlChild = XmlParser.getChildren(xmlRoot);
                for ( int index = 0; index < xmlChild.length; ++index )
                {
                    UserContent item = new UserContent();
                    Element[] contentNodes = XmlParser.getChildren(xmlChild[index]);
                    for ( int i = 0; i < contentNodes.length; ++i )
                    {
                        if (contentNodes[i].getName().equals(StaticStrings.contentUserID))
                        {
                            item.id = contentNodes[i].getText(0);
                        }
                        else if (contentNodes[i].getName().equals(StaticStrings.contentUserPIB))
                        {
                            item.pib = contentNodes[i].getText(0);
                        }
                        else if (contentNodes[i].getName().equals(StaticStrings.contentUserPhone))
                        {
                            item.phone = contentNodes[i].getText(0);
                        }
                        else if (contentNodes[i].getName().equals(StaticStrings.contentUserMail))
                        {
                            item.email = contentNodes[i].getText(0);
                        }
                    }
                    result.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            isr.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}

    }
    return result;
}
```

But when I call this method, I get all the xml tags but their content is null.

Answer (score 0):

a more straightforward way might be to use an XML serialization framework. if you were using pure Java that might be JAXB, but for Android [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) is a good choice. it a nutshell, you create a POJO then annotate it indicate how you want to serialize / deserialize. for example,

```
@Root(name = "Client")
class Client {

  @Attribute(name = "ID")
  private String id;

  ...
}
```

then to deserialize,

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
String xml = ...; // get your XML into a string, or a stream
Client client = serializer.read(Client.class, xml);
```